# Cannot resolve symbols AppCompatActivity and GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, appcompatactivity, android-googleapiclient

I am new to developing on Android Studio, my app was running fine until the studio exited abruptly after that the project cannot find any of the libraries imported (in asterisks) like `Uri`, `AppCompatActivity` etc to  my `AppCompatActivity` class (I am using Android 2.1.2)

```
import android.net.*Uri*;
import android.os.*Bundle*;
import android.support.v7.*;
import android.util.*Log*;
import android.view.*View*;
import android.widget.*AdapterView*;
import android.widget.*ListView*;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.*Action*;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.*AppIndex*;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.*GoogleApiClient*;

import org.xmlpull.v1.*XmlPullParser*;
import org.xmlpull.v1.*XmlPullParserException*;
import org.xmlpull.v1.*XmlPullParserFactory*;

import java.io.*IOException*;
import java.io.*InputStream*;
import java.util.*ArrayList*;
import java.util.*List*;

public class Menu extends android.support.v7.app.*AppCompatActivity* {
```

What I have tried uptil now:

1. checked projectstructure -> app -> dependencies
2. tried sequencing the libs

   com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1
   com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0
   before junit:junit:4.12
3. Checked build.gradle and added above 2 dependencies
4. Clean Project
5. Build APK
6. ReBuild Project (many times)

P.S: com.google.android... imports were auto generated with onstart and onstop overrides (no idea why)

```
// ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
```

P.S: My Android Studio is installed in C:/Programfiles and my project is saved in a different location under AndroidStudioProjects folder

Comment: Try to sync your project with gradle.

Comment: already did many times mate